# Return a pointer to class member function

Tags: c++, pointers, gcc, c++11, pointer-to-member

The following Problem drives me nuts, though it doesn't seem very odd:

```
class Foo;

// This is the location of the first error code
//        ↓
int (Foo::*)(int) getPointer()
{
    return 0;
}
```

GCC gives me:

```
error: expected unqualified-id before ')' token
error: expected initializer before 'getPointer'
```

PS: I compile with -std=c++11

Comment: For God's sake use typedefs

Comment: @Slava Totally agree, but it's also nice to understand how it works.

Comment: @Slava I cannot, since the return type is dependent of a deduced template parameter and you cannot typedef between 'template<>' and 'getPointer()'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int ( Foo::* ( getPointer() ) )();
```

That being said, remember you can use `typedef`. For function pointers, it usually improves the overall readability:

```
typedef int ( Foo::* TypeName )();

TypeName getPointer();
```

Answer (score 0):

use a typedef, like:

```
class Foo;

typedef int (Foo::*POINTER)(int);

POINTER getPointer()
{
    return 0;
}
```

For more reasoning here goes: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/typedef-for-ptr-to-memfn.html

Comment: It is usually bad idea to use all uppercase identifiers.

Comment: It usually depends on the coding standard your company decided to adopt.

Comment: to use uppercase identifiers for preprocessor does not seem to be a company coding standard, but used everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to use function pointers, but not giving a name to it :P

Use this:

```
int (Foo::*myPointer)(int) getPointer()
{
    return 0;
}
```